# FullCalendar RefetchEvents very slow

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

I call `calendar.refetchEvents();`  inside an autorun Block to ensure the reactivity of the Scheduler (i'm using resource view) , when tested with big datasets , although i make sure to subscript to only a portion of 2 weeks worth of events , it's extremly slow .

my events arent Json based i'm using meteor and i loop over the events inside the Events function of the calendar .
are there some good fullcalendar practices i'm missing ?

```
calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        now: new Date(),
        editable: true, // enable draggable events
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
        aspectRatio: 1.8,
        disableDragging: true,
        displayEventTime: false,
        selectable:true,
        allDaySlot:true,
        slotDuration:'24:00',
        lazyFetching:true,
        scrollTime: '00:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
        header: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineThreeDays'
        },
        defaultView: 'timelineThreeDays',
        views: {
            timelineThreeDays: {
                type: 'timeline',
                duration: { days: 14 }
            }
        },
        eventAfterAllRender: function(){
            Session.set("loading",false);
        },
        resourceLabelText: 'Employees',
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            var originalClass = element[0].className;

            if (event.id && event.id.indexOf("temp")>-1){
                element[0].className = originalClass + ' dragEvent';
            }
            else if (event.id && event.id.indexOf("oloc")>-1){
                element[0].className = originalClass + ' oloc';
            }
            else{
                element[0].className = originalClass + ' hasmenu';
            }
            $(element[0]).attr('shift-id', event._id);

            element.find('.fc-title').html((event.title?event.title+"<br/>":"")+(event.locationName?event.locationName+"<br/>":"")+moment(event.start).format("HH:mm")+ " "+moment(event.end).format("HH:mm"));
            element.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
                if (e.which == 3) {
                    Session.set("selectedShift",event._id);
                }
            });

        },eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {

        },
        resourceRender: function(resourceObj, labelTds, bodyTds) {
            var originalClass = labelTds[0].className;
            var uid=resourceObj.id;
            var resource = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:uid});
            if(resource){
                var img = Images.findOne({_id: resource.picture});
                var imgUrl = img ? img.url() : "/images/default-avatar.png";
                var styleString = "<img class='img-profil small' src='"+imgUrl+"'>" + resource.profile.firstname + " " + resource.profile.lastname+" <small style='font-size:0.6em;color:#D24D57;'>"+resource.profile.registeredTelephony+"</small>";
                labelTds.find('.fc-cell-text').html("");
                labelTds.find('.fc-cell-text').prepend(styleString);
                labelTds[0].className = originalClass + ' hasResourceMenu';
            }else{
                var imgUrl = "/images/default-avatar.png";
                var styleString = "<img class='img-profil small' src='"+imgUrl+"'>" + "Unassigned" + " " +" <small style='font-size:0.6em;color:#D24D57;'>"+"</small>";
                labelTds.find('.fc-cell-text').html("");
                labelTds.find('.fc-cell-text').prepend(styleString);
            }

        },
        resources: function(callback) {
            var users = [];
            var data = Meteor.users.find({
                $or:[
                    {"profile.showInScheduler":{$exists:false}},
                    {"profile.showInScheduler":true}
                ],
                assignedTo:{$in:[Session.get("locationId")]},
                'locations._id':Session.get("locationId"),
                "profile.companyId":Session.get("companyId")
            });

            var arr = data.map(function(c) {
                var employeeType = c.userSettings.employeeType;
                var type = EmployeeType.findOne({_id:employeeType});
                var img = Images.findOne({_id: c.picture});
                var imgUrl = img ? img.url() : "/images/default-avatar.png";
                c.name = c.name || "";

                var totalHoursAllLocation = 0;
                var totalHoursCurrentLocation = 0;
                return {
                    id: c._id,
                    title: "t"
                };
            });
            arr.push({id:"temp"+Session.get("companyId")+Session.get("locationId"),title:"<div class='img-profil small' style='background: url(/images/default-avatar.png);'></div> UnAssigned"});
            callback(arr);
        },
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        },
        drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var locationId=Session.get("locationId");
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            //copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            shift = ShiftTypes.findOne({_id:copiedEventObject.id});
            if(shift){

                startDate = moment(date);
                hour = shift.dayDuration.Start.split(":");
                startDate.hours(hour[0]).minutes(hour[1]);
                endDate = moment(date);
                hour = shift.dayDuration.End.split(":");
                endDate.hours(hour[0]).minutes(hour[1]);
                if(moment(startDate).isAfter(endDate)){
                    endDate=endDate.add("1","days");
                }
                var data = {
                    shiftId:shift._id,
                    name:shift.name,
                    uid:resourceId,
                    locationId:Session.get("locationId"),
                    companyId:Session.get("companyId"),
                    day:date,start:startDate.utc().toDate(),
                    end:endDate.utc().toDate(),
                    type:"active"
                };

                if (SchedulesBeforeInsert(data,"dropActive")){
                    Schedules.insert(data,function (err,result) {});
                }

            }

        },
        eventResize: function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
            endDate = moment.utc(new Date(event.start));
            schedule = Schedules.findOne({_id:event.id});
            var delta = dayDelta._days;
            for(i=1;i<delta+1;i++){
                Schedules.insert({start:moment.utc(event.start).add(i,"days").toDate(),end:moment.utc(schedule.end).add(i,"days").toDate(),uid:schedule.uid,locationId:Session.get("locationId"),companyId:schedule.companyId,name:schedule.name,shiftId:schedule.shiftId,attendanceCode:schedule.attendanceCode,type:schedule.type});
            }
        },
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view,res,res2) {
            Session.set("selectedDay",moment(date).toDate());
            Session.set("selectedRessource",res.id);

        },
        eventClick: function ( event, jsEvent, view )  {

            toastr.success(moment(event.start).format('HH:mm') +" TO "+moment(event.endDate).format('HH:mm'))

        },
        eventReceive: function(event) { // called when a proper external event is dropped
            console.log('eventReceive', event);
        }
    }).data().fullCalendar;

/********************* reactive calendar *****************/

this.autorun(function() {
    console.log("autoRun")
    Meteor.subscribe("schedules",Session.get("companyId"),moment($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate')).startOf('week').toDate(),moment($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate')).add(4,"weeks").endOf('week').toDate());
    var events = [];
    var usersInLocation = Meteor.users.find({$or:[{"profile.showInScheduler":{$exists:false}},{"profile.showInScheduler":true}],assignedTo:{$in:[Session.get("locationId")]},'locations._id':Session.get("locationId"),"profile.companyId":Session.get("companyId")}).fetch();
    var userIds = _.pluck(usersInLocation,"_id");
    userIds.push("temp"+Session.get("companyId")+Session.get("locationId"));
    var data;
    if(Session.get("displayAllLocations")===true){
        reqEvents = Schedules.find({uid:{$in:userIds},companyId:Session.get("companyId"),type:{$in:["active","activeAttendance"]},start:{$gte:moment(Session.get("currentDate")).startOf('week').toDate()},end:{$lte:moment(Session.get("currentDate")).add(1,"week").endOf('week').toDate()}});
    }else{
        reqEvents = Schedules.find({uid:{$in:userIds},locationId:Session.get("locationId"),companyId:Session.get("companyId"),type:{$in:["active","activeAttendance"]},start:{$gte:moment(Session.get("currentDate")).startOf('week').toDate()},end:{$lte:moment(Session.get("currentDate")).add(1,"week").endOf('week').toDate()}});

    }
    reqEvents.forEach(function(evt){
        var event = null;
        color="";
        if(evt.attendanceCode){
            attendance =AttendanceCodes.findOne({_id:evt.attendanceCode});
            color=attendance.color;
        }
        attendance = null;
        color="";
        id="";
        locationName="";
        if(evt.attendanceCode){
            attendance =AttendanceCodes.findOne({_id:evt.attendanceCode})
            if(attendance){
                color=attendance.color;
            }

        }
        else if(evt.employeeAttendanceCode){
            attendance =AttendanceCodesPortal.findOne({_id:evt.employeeAttendanceCode})
            if(attendance){
                color=attendance.color;
            }
        }
        id=evt._id;
        if(evt.locationId!==Session.get("locationId")){
            color="#EEEEEE";
            id="oloc";
            location =Locations.findOne({_id:evt.locationId});
            if(location){
                locationName=location.name;
            }

        }
        if(evt.name != null){
            event = {id:id,title:evt.name,start:evt.start,end:evt.end,color:color,resourceId:evt.uid,locationName:locationName};
        }else{
            event = {id:id,title:" ",start:evt.start,end:evt.end,color:color,resourceId:evt.uid,locationName:locationName};
        }
        events.push(event);
    });


    allUsersCursor =Meteor.users.find({
        $or:[
            {"profile.showInScheduler":{$exists:false}},
            {"profile.showInScheduler":true}
        ],
        assignedTo:{$in:[Session.get("locationId")]},
        'locations._id':Session.get("locationId"),
        "profile.companyId":Session.get("companyId")
    }).fetch();


    if(calendar){
        calendar.removeEvents();
        calendar.addEventSource(events);
        calendar.refetchResources();
        //SetUp the actions context menu
        setUpContextMenu();

        // Initialize the external events
        $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                id:$(this).attr("id")
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: 'invalid',
                appendTo: 'body'// original position after the drag
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Network? Can you show code?

Comment: i just added some code , thank you

Answer (score 3):

I can see a number of non-Meteoric patterns in there that you should optimize out:

1. Your `this.autorun` will rerun anytime anything changes in your `Schedules` collection as well as for various user object changes (not just to the logged-in users but other users as well). Your autorun rebuilds your client-side data from scratch every time, including numerous joins. You could use a [local collection](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html) to cache the joined data and then only add/change those documents when the underlying persisted document changes. This can be done with an [observeChanges](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges) pattern. Or you could denormalize your data model a bit to avoid all those joins.
2. You're modifying the DOM by attaching events to a number of selectors using jQuery instead of using Meteor event handlers. This is also happening in your autorun which means you're attaching the same events to the same DOM objects repeatedly.
3. You use many `Session` variables and you use them repeatedly. These can be slow since they use browser local storage. You should `.get()` such data into a local variable once only and then refer to the local variable from then on.
4. Make sure that you only include fields in your `Schedules` publication that your code actually refers to on the client. The rest are overhead.